# Android App using AWS Cognito, Google+ OAuth, and AccountManager

Tags: android, oauth, google-plus, amazon-cognito, accountmanager

I've been trying to setup Google+ OAuth and AWS Cognito on my Android app.  Right now I have Google+ OAuth working I believe, because I'm able to get the account off the call below:

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
```

From that result object I can get certain data outlined below:

```
   if (result.isSuccess()) {

    GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
    String authCode = account.getServerAuthCode(); //null
    String displayName =account.getDisplayName(); //correct value
    String email = account.getEmail(); //correct value
    String id = account.getId(); //correct value
    String idToken = account.getIdToken(); //null
...
```

However, when I follow AWS's documentation, I get errors and deprecated methods.  Here's the code block I'm trying to mimic from AWS's documentation:

Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/google.html#set-up-google-1.android#Android

```
//From Documentation ^ 
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accounts[0].name,
            "audience:server:client_id:YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID");
    Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
    logins.put("accounts.google.com", token);
    credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
```

Here is where I'm running into problems:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
            Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
```

After this call accounts is an empty array--do I need to do something to ensure the OAuth process puts the information in the AccountManager?

*** One other thing I wasn't sure about, the AWS documentation (from the link above) states as Step #5 for setting up google that I should do the following steps which I can't seem to get right:  "Under Credentials > Add Credentials, create a Service Account. The console will alert you that a new public/private key has been created."

Google has changed their UI and there are now 3 options, creating a custom service account, and using one of two default accounts (app engine / computation engine).  Which should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.  Key changes from the Amazon aws and google documentation.

1. GoogleSignInOptions needs to ask for an id token.  You do this like so:

   ```
   googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
           .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)) //<- this is optional
           //requestIdToken takes the google cloud console's project's WEB (not Android)
           .requestIdToken("in this string put your google web client id")
           .requestEmail()
           .build();
   ```
2. Then when you get the results back you'll have the id token

   ```
   GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
   GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
   String idToken = account.getIdToken();
   ```
3. Now you can use that id token to gain aws credentials through cognito.

   Map logins = new HashMap();
   logins.put("accounts.google.com", token);
   credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins); 
   //credentialsProvider=CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider

Now you should be all set.